# Nightwatch get test_settings name in global after method

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am tasked with pushing out a nightwatch report to sharepoint. I have it all working I just need to get the test_settings name in the globals.js file's 'after' method so after the test completes and the report is generated I can name it by the date-env-user.

**Background:**
I am using a `env.json` file for all the consistent environment variables between environments.
In my `nightwatch.conf.js` file I have multiple 'test_settings' environments like 'local', 'qa', etc.

I want to get that value 'local' or 'qa' when I am in the `globals.js` file's 'after()' method.

I tried process.env.environment, browser.globals.environment (but 'browser' is not available in `globals.js`). I also tried some other variations from other articles I found, to no avail.

Here's my `nightwatch.conf.js` pertinent test_Settings values:

```
"test_settings": {
    "local": {
        "launch_url":"http://example.local",
        "screenshots": {
            "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
            "path": './reports/screenshots/local' // save screenshots here
        },
        "globals": {
            "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
            "browserName": "chrome"
        }
    },
    "qa": {
        "launch_url": "https://qa.example.com",
        "screenshots": {
            "enabled": true, // if you want to keep screenshots
            "path": './reports/screenshots/qa' // save screenshots here
        },
        "globals": {
            "waitForConditionTimeout": 5000 // sometimes internet is slow so wait.
        },
        "desiredCapabilities": { // use Chrome as the default browser for tests
            "browserName": "chrome"
        }
    },
```

and this is a example command line I am calling tests with

> node_modules/.bin/nightwatch --env local --config nightwatch.conf.BASIC.js --test test\e2e\search.js --reporter ./report
>   s/reporter.js

I want to extract 'local' or 'qa' from inside the `globals.js/after()` method.
again, but 'browser' is not available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna share the way we do it in our project and hope this applies to you as well:

```
let activeEnvironment = require("minimist")(process.argv)["env"];
```

This way you can save the given environment variable. 
If that doesnt work in the 'after' method, you could write this to a temp file and read it in the 'after' mehtod.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked as expected. Thanks a lot! I used it in reports.js for the HtmpReporter too so each env report goes into it's specific folder before uploading to sharepoint. This really helped.